# Skewness of distribution vs. skewness of distribution's PDF

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I'm having trouble understanding why the skewness of built-in distributions is not the same as the skewness of their probability density functions.  For example, the following are different (the first being correct):

```
Skewness[NormalDistribution[0, 1]]
Skewness[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], Table[x, {x, -4, 4, 0.1}]]]
```

..despite them both being (looking?) the same:

```
Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x], {x, -4, 4}]
ListPlot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], Table[x, {x, -4, 4, 0.1}]]]
```

What I'm trying to do is estimate the skewness of a distribution resulting from a numerically solved PDE model (i.e. a distribution for which I have no analytical solution).  Mathematica's skewness function is giving me positive skewness estimates even when the distribution is clearly negatively-skewed.  Thanks.

---

@Szabolcs
The PDE itself is rather "complicated" (boundary conditions, etc.), so I’ll try illustrate with a simpler version (which, unfortunately, doesn’t exhibit the negative skew of the complete model):

```
deqn = D[u[x, t], t] == d D[u[x, t], x, x] - a  D[u[x, t], x] - \[Lambda] u[x, t]

g[x_, \[Epsilon]_]:=Piecewise[{{0,x<0}, {1,0<=x<=\[Epsilon]}, {0,x>\[Epsilon]}}]

d=0.02; \[Lambda]=0.001; a=0.05;

sol=NDSolve[{deqn, u[x,0]==g[x,0.1], u[-10,t]==0, u[10,t]==0}, u, {x,-10,10}, {t,0,300}]

Plot3D[Evaluate[u[x,t]/.sol[[1]]], {x,-10,10}, {t,0,300}, PlotPoints->40, Mesh->False, PlotRange->All, AxesLabel->{length, time, density}]

Plot[Evaluate[{u[1, t]/.sol[[1]], u[5,t]/.sol[[1]]}], {t,0,300}, AxesLabel->{time, density}, PlotRange->All]
```

It is the skewness of the two distributions in the second plot that I'm after.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the PDF of the distribution with numbers that are distributed according to it.

---

`Skewness` works on distribution objects such as `NormalDistribution` and gives the skewness of that distribution.

`Skewness` also works on a list of data points and gives the *skewness of the distribution of the data* (or an estimate of it).

`PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], Table[x, {x, -4, 4, 0.1}]]` computes the probability density function of the normal distribution at regularly spaced points.  *These number are not normally distributed.*

These are normally distributed: `RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0,1], 1000]`.  Their skewness will be close to zero.

Comment: Yes, of course, that now makes perfect sense.  Thanks for the quick response. However, despite the clarification on the question I posed, I still can't figure out how to solve my underlying problem: determining the skewness of a slice through my PDE solution.  I'll add text to my original question to explain.  Thanks

Comment: @user12734 What is the definition of skewness?  Use the definition directly to derive the integral in terms of your function, then use Mathematica to numerically evaluate the integral.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following.
     CentralMoment[list,3]/CentralMoment[list,2]^(3/2)
or
     $\frac{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}{n-2}\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \bar{x})^3}{(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{n=1}^{n}(x_i - \bar{x})^2)^{3/2}}$

Comment: @user12734 That definition is valid for a set of points drawn from some distribution.  It sounds like you want the skewness of *a function*.  The first question for you is: *what is the skewness of a function (not distribution)?*  I'm not asking you what the function `Skewness` does.  I am asking you to tell me, in precise mathematical terms (not code), what you want to calculate.

Comment: If your supervisor asked you to calculate the "skewness" and you're not sure what he meant, you should ask him.

Comment: One way to do it would be to obtain the distribution that corresponds to the PDF that you already have (does someone know if Mathematica will do that?). Another way is to get back to the formulae to compute expected values and skewness directly from the PDF (skewness $=\int... $, etc; see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness)

Comment: @A.G. Yes, `ProbabilityDistribution` does that, but it is the user's responsibility to make sure that the PDF used in `ProbabilityDistribution` is actually normalized.  If it is not, many functions will silently (i.e. without error messages) return wrong results.

Comment: Thanks to you both!  Here's a simplified version of what ended up working for me.
A = ProbabilityDistribution[
   Evaluate[Eqn[x, t]], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}];
B = PDF[A, t][[1, 1, 1]];
C = ProbabilityDistribution[B/Integrate[B, {t, 0, \[Infinity]}]];
data = RandomVariate[C, 1000];